# Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit is not working very well in my PC

Tags: ram, cpu

```
>  System:    Kernel: 4.2.0-32-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Unity 7.3.3  Distro: Ubuntu 15.10 wily
CPU:       Single core Intel Pentium 4 (-HT-) cache: 1024 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 3066 MHz 1: 3066 MHz 2: 3066 MHz

> Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GT218 [GeForce 210]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.17.2 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
            Resolution: 1440x900@59.89hz
            GLX Renderer: GeForce 210/PCIe/SSE2
            GLX Version: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 340.96

Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (2.3% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST500DM002 size: 500.1GB

Memory:    Array-1 capacity: 4 GB devices: 2 EC: None
           Device-1: DIMM1 size: 2 GB speed: 532 MHz type: SDRAM
           Device-2: DIMM2 size: No Module Installed type: N/A
```

But it is  working so slowly (opening software and etc.)
What do you think I should do ?

Comment: Please add whether you installed Ubuntu 15.10 32 or 64 bit, which desktop environment you use and what graphics card and driver. There's a useful system information script called "inxi". You install it and let it display the required information using the commands `sudo apt-get install inxi` and `inxi -SCDG ; sudo inxi -m`.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu might be a bit heavy for an old Pentium 4, would probably be better to try a lighter version of 'buntu such as Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: it is new, about 4 years

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether it was the 64bit or 32bit version you have installed.

Keep an eye on your hard drive activity, it may indicate that you are swapping too much from RAM.  The command 'free' will tell you how much free RAM or memory you have.  It could be just a simple case of installing more memory if you have it.

The command `hdparm -Tt /dev/sda` will test your drive for read speeds, might not actually be of any benefit unless glaringly slow.
The program 'smartctl' can be installed by typing `apt-get install smartmontools` at the terminal, and after it's installed by running `smartctl -d ata -a /dev/sda`.  It will report a good amount of information for you.

*IF* you have spare parts laying around, I would replace your hard drive, as installation take only a few minutes, versus several hours perhaps of diagnosing.

Comment: It would be better to check the drive for errors with some special software before changing it. **MHDD** is one of such programs, it can be found here: http://hddguru.com/software/ .

Comment: This is a guess out of the blue and in my humble opinion not really useful.